# Incrementing string value in PHP

Tags: php, string

I have range of strings starting with random amount of letters (from 0 to more than 10) and ending with numbers:

example 1: S001, S002, ..., S015

example 2: AB67116, AB67117, ..., AB67128

example 3: G07, G08, G09, G10, G11

How can I generate all of them in array if I'm given just the starting one and the ending one?

e.g. from ZS11 to ZS15 I need an array with ZS11, ZS12, ZS13, ZS14, ZS15

Already tried:

```
for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {
    //code here
}
```

, where $start is the starting string and $end is the last one

EDIT: with S1 to S10 stops at S1

Comment: then what problem you get?

Comment: with iterating just the last digit executes properly, but with more than one breaks after first iteration.

Comment: Not sure if my answer response to your question but first you need the start and end numbers. next time you have to put down the complete code to see in what your code is failing the "for" only is not showing how you get start and end

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider

- Validate the start number and the end number
- The order letter/number

Code

```
function generateCode($starting_code, $end_code)
{

    preg_match_all('/([a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+)/', $starting_code, $arr_start);
    preg_match_all('/([a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+)/', $end_code, $arr_end);

    $generated = [];

    $start = $arr_start[0][1];
    $end = $arr_end[0][1];
    $string_code = $arr_start[0][0];

    if (!is_numeric($start) || !is_numeric($end)) {
        return "Invalid Imput!\n";
    }

    $len = strlen($start);
    for ($index = $start; $index <= $end; $index++) {
        $code_number = str_pad($index, $len, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);;
        $generated[] = (string)$string_code . $code_number;
    }

    return $generated;
}
```

Use

```
$starting_code = "ZA11";
$end_code = "ZA15";

$codes = generateCode($starting_code, $end_code);
print_r($codes);
```

> Result

```
    Array
(
        [0] => S01
        [1] => S02
        [2] => S03
        [3] => S04
        [4] => S05
        [5] => S06
        [6] => S07
        [7] => S08
        [8] => S09
        [9] => S10
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Editing the question realized why it didn't work with simple 'for'.

Strings must have same length to work, dummy me.

in the data set it is S01 to S10, not S1 to S10.